# How to count the number of unique items based on another column and add it to the existing dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a data frame in which I need to find the count of unique values based on the other column, I have found the unique values but I want to add the count values to the existing data frame based on one column.

The df looks like.

| lot_id_x | space_id |
| --- | --- |
| 2606 | 101 |
| 2606 | 102 |
| 2606 | 101 |
| 2606 | 103 |
| 2606 | 104 |
| 2606 | 104 |
| 2606 | 101 |
| 534 | 11 |
| 534 | 12 |
| 534 | 12 |
| 534 | 13 |
| 534 | 11 |
| 670 | 6 |
| 670 | 6 |
| 670 | 9 |
| 670 | 9 |
| 670 | 21 |
| -------- | -------- |

I have used

```
count = df.groupby('lot_id_x')['space_id'].nunique().sort_values(ascending=False).reset_index(name='count')
count
```

I have got the result as

| No | lot_id_x | count |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 2606 | 161 |
| 1 | 534 | 109 |
| 2 | 670 | 108 |
| 3 | 343 | 101 |
| -- | -------- | ----- |

But how can I add this result into the existing data frame df?
The output will look like this,

| lot_id_x | space_id | count |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2606 | 101 | 161 |
| 2606 | 102 | 161 |
| 2606 | 101 | 161 |
| 2606 | 103 | 161 |
| 2606 | 104 | 161 |
| 2606 | 104 | 161 |
| 2606 | 101 | 161 |
| 534 | 11 | 109 |
| 534 | 12 | 109 |
| 534 | 12 | 109 |
| 534 | 13 | 109 |
| 534 | 11 | 109 |
| 670 | 6 | 108 |
| 670 | 6 | 108 |
| 670 | 9 | 108 |
| 670 | 9 | 108 |
| 670 | 21 | 108 |
| -------- | -------- | ----- |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC:

you need `transform()`+`sort_values()`:

```
df['count']=df.groupby('lot_id_x')['space_id'].transform('nunique')
df=df.sort_values('count',ascending=False,ignore_index=True)
```

OR

In single step via `assign()`:

```
df=(df.assign(count=df.groupby('lot_id_x')['space_id'].transform('nunique'))
      .sort_values('count',ascending=False,ignore_index=True))
```